# Laravel 4 - Controller not found

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am working on an application with laravel which saves files in database and to a destination folder. I am trying to delete a record from the database but all I get is an error which says that the controller method is not found.

Error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Controller method not found.

throw new NotFoundHttpException("Controller method not found.");
```

The view alluploads.blade.php has a form, where it should pass the id to the uploads/destroy function.

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'url' => array('uploads/destroy', $upload->id))) }}
     {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And my controller has the function that deletes the row.

```
public function getDestroy($id)
{
     $this->upload->find($id)->delete();
     return Redirect::to('uploads/alluploads')->with('message', 'Thanks, delete was successful!');
}
```

The routes are have the following to access functions under uploads controller

```
Route::controller('uploads', 'UploadsController');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using HTTP method DELETE, so your controller method should be:

```
public function deleteDestroy($id)
{
     $this->upload->find($id)->delete();
     return Redirect::to('uploads/alluploads')->with('message', 'Thanks, delete was successful!');
}
```

Take a look at your routes:

```
php artisan routes
```

You must see, at least, something like this there:

```
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                                           | Name                 | Action                                                | Before Filters                 | After Filters |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+
|        | DELETE uploads/destroy/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |                      | UploadsController@deleteDestroy                       |                                |               |
|        | GET uploads/{_missing}                                        |                      | UploadsController@missingMethod                       |                                |               |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+
```

To use your form the way it is your form open line would have to be:

```
Form::open(array('method' => 'GET', 'url' => array('uploads/destroy', $upload->id)))
```

But I think it's better the way it is now, just rename your method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Antonio, it works. I am working with php arisan routes in terminal and its very helpful. I didn't know that deleteDestroy would work, I though that just post and get were working. Thanks again!

Comment: That's helpful, http://laravel.com/docs/controllers. And if i'll change my form open line to have a get method instead of delete it still gives me an error. All, I did was to change my method's name as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

First try what you have with just uploads/ instead of uploads/destroy.  The route name for delete is resource.destroy but the url is resource/{id} called with the delete verb

Here is how I open my form to create a delete button if $uploads is an index of uploads

```
@foreach($uploads as $upload)
    {{ Form::model($upload, array('url' => 'uploads/'. $upload->id, 'method' => 'delete')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('delete') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
@endofreach
```